# Subtracting month from date is not giving correct value in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i am trying to subtract the month from Date its not giving accurate result

```
end_date = Date.parse("30-09-2019")
end_date - 1.months
```

## returns 30 - aug - 2019

```
example 30-09-2019 - 1.month to give 31 - 08 - 2019
example 15-09-2019 - 1.month to give 14 - 08 - 2019
```

Comment: please add what is the issue, what error are you getting and what is your expected output?

Comment: It appears you posted this question 6 hours ago, hung around for 5 minutes and then disappeared. That's not a good idea, and somewhat inconsiderate, as questions are likely to arise that will go unanswered for a very long time.

Answer (score 2):

The reason `Date.new(2019, 9, 30) - 1.month` results in `Fri, 30 Aug 2019` is simply because `1.month` isn't 30 days, but a static value of 2629746 seconds (30.436875 days).

```
date = Date.new(2019, 9, 30)

1.month == 30.436875.days #=> true

date - 30.days        #=> Sat, 31 Aug 2019
date - 30.436875.days #=> Fri, 30 Aug 2019
```

You can find these static values documented [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html).

Comment: As someone who does not know Rails I am perplexed how the method `month` can be used to advantage. I see that `12 * 30.436875 #=> 365.2425` so it's clearly a weighted average (even accounting for the leap-year rule concerning the first year of each century). Can you explain briefly where the method is used?

Comment: @CarySwoveland What do you mean by *"Can you explain briefly where the method is used?"* What method should be explained?

Comment: Yes, I inferred how `365.24215` is calculated. My question: in what situation would it be helpful to be able to use the method `Integer#month`?

Comment: I can't really think much scenario's where `Integer#month` would be useful, since the length varies and Rails simply took the average (just like the do with `#year`). They might be useful in scenario's where you don't have to work with exact dates. However the helpers `Integer#minute`, `#hour`, `#day` and `#week` are useful, since those don't fluctuate in length.

Comment: In that case I think Rails should have more weighted-average (`Integer`) methods for completeness: `decade`, `century`, `millennium`, `mega_anuum`,  `galactic_year`, ...

Comment: @CarySwoveland `x.months.ago` is actually useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches you can use to subtract months from a date in Ruby, the following guide is pretty comprehensive on all the date manipulation methods you can perform in Ruby:

[Ruby Cookbook, 2nd Edition by Leonard Richardson, Lucas Carlson](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/ruby-cookbook-2nd/9781449373702/ch04.html)

**1. Using << (method)**

```
require 'date'

end_date = Date.parse("30-09-2019")
end_date = end_date << 1
print(end_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```

**2. Using prev_month()**

```
require 'date'

end_date = Date.parse("30-09-2019")
end_date = end_date.prev_month //this would give the desired result
print(end_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DateTime#advance`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-advance) from ActiveSupport.

> Uses Date to provide precise Time calculations for years, months, and
>   days. The options parameter takes a hash with any of these keys:
>   :years, :months, :weeks, :days, :hours, :minutes, :seconds.

```
irb(main):001:0> end_date = Date.parse("30-09-2019")
=> Mon, 30 Sep 2019
irb(main):002:0> end_date.advance(months: 1)
=> Wed, 30 Oct 2019
irb(main):003:0> end_date.advance(months: -1)
=> Fri, 30 Aug 2019
irb(main):004:0> end_date.advance(months: -1, days: 2)
=> Sun, 01 Sep 2019
```

And yeah using `.advance` to go backwards is semantically strange but it works fine with negative values. Unfortunately there is no inverse method.

Comment: it will be same

Comment: You have the wrong expectations. One month before 30-09-2019 is 30-08-2019. Thats how calendars work. A month before is not the same as -30 days. Its the same date on the previous month. If you advance 31-01-2019 by one month you would get 28-02-2019 since the next month only has 28 days.